# jsPDF download pdf file of markup on click on button

Tags: jquery, pdf, download, jspdf

I'm trying to download resume pdf file of html markup that I've done according to the jsPDF's documentation. On click, the resume pdf is actually downloading but the pdf is blank.

The [JSfiddle with full code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/rrhowg9a/); my JS function looks like this:

```
$('.btn-download').click(function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    //var source = $('#target').html();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '.btn-download': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    doc.fromHTML($('#content').get(0), 0.5, 0.5, {
        'width': 150,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save("resume-cv.pdf");
});
```

Comment: Any one can assist me would be highly appreciable. I can be able to donwload pdf file, but the markup text wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
$("button").click (function() {

var doc = new jsPDF();



doc.fromHTML($('#testdiv').get(0), 30,20,{
             'width':500,

});
doc.addPage();

doc.fromHTML($('#testdiv').get(0), 30,20,{
             'width':500,

});
doc.save('Devis-Facture.pdf');

});
```

Comment: Thanks Michael_B for helping me out on this matter. I've tried this but unfortunately its still not working for me, still same blank pdf document is downloaded. And console also throwing following error - "jsPDF Warning: rendering issues? provide a callback to fromHTML!"